# Adding elements to a 2 dimensional array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, element

I’m writing this code where I fill a 2 dimensional array with information from a file. Here’s the file:

```
5 

Franks,Tom 2 3 8 3 6 3 5 

Gates,Bill 8 8 3 0 8 2 0 

Jordan,Michael 9 10 4 7 0 0 0 

Bush,George  5 6 5 6 5 6 5 

Heinke,Lonnie  7 3 8 7 2 5 7
```

Now the numbers are going in the array: `data[50][8]`.

I also total all the numbers in each line which I have done. I want to add this total to the data array so it looks something like `2 3 8 3 6 5 3 30`. How do I do this? 
Here’s all my code if you wanted to see it:

```
int main()
{

    ifstream fin;
    char ch;
    int data[50][8];
    string names[50];

    fin.open("empdata.txt");

    int sum = 0;
    int numOfNames;
    fin >> numOfNames;

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfNames; i++) {

        fin >> names[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            fin >> data[i][j];
        }
            }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
                sum += data[i][j];

            }
            cout << sum << endl;
            sum = 0;
        }
}
```

Here's the new code that c650 helped me with. It's not outputting anything now:
int main()
{

```
ifstream fin;
char ch;
int data[50][8];
string names[50];

fin.open("empdata.txt");

int sum = 0;
int numOfNames;
fin >> numOfNames;

for (int i = 0; i < numOfNames; i++) {

    fin >> names[i];

    data[i][7] = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        fin >> data[i][j];
        data[i][7] += data[i][j];
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < numOfNames; i++)
{
    cout << data[i][7] << endl;

}



system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Please format the file...

Comment: I just did. Hope that helps

Comment: I'd recommend you use the STL. A `std::vector` may really help you out!

Comment: I have to use arrays

Comment: Will there always be seven numbers after each name?

Comment: first add 2 matrix by simple addition and contain the sum in **sum** matrix.then using a for loop try to print the **sum** matrix.

Comment: yes there will always be 7 @c650

Comment: "How do I do this?" -- you write the code to do it. It looks like you have a good grasp on all the basic concepts: how to write a loop, how to use variables, how to add things. You already have a loop that reads each one of the eight numbers on every line. So what exactly about computing their sum do you have a problem with?

Comment: @ShahrairNazimReal Id rather not use matrixes. I haven't learned about those yet

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It's putting the sum into the array that I don't know how to do. That's what I need help with

Comment: Well, once a sum is computed, it's like any other number. You already have existing code that adds a number read from a file into the array. Adding a variable containing the sum of the read values, into the same array, is done in exactly the same way.

Comment: @Ralf you konw how to use 2D array.A matrix is nothing but an array where i specified coloum of matrix and j specified row of matrix.

Comment: @Ralf I think I know the problem you're now facing... See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems like what you are trying to do. I will point the flaws in the code you've presented.

This is not the best way to do it, but according to OP there are some constraints, such as not being able to use the STL.

```
/*  1 */  #include <fstream>
/*  2 */  #include <iostream>
/*  3 */  #include <string>
/*  4 */  
/*  5 */  using namespace std;
/*  6 */  int main()
/*  7 */  {
/*  8 */  
/*  9 */      ifstream fin;
/* 10 */      int data[50][8];
/* 11 */      string names[50];
/* 12 */  
/* 13 */      fin.open("test.txt");
/* 14 */  
/* 15 */      int numOfNames;
/* 16 */      fin >> numOfNames;
/* 17 */  
/* 18 */      for (int i = 0; i < numOfNames; i++) {
/* 19 */  
/* 20 */          fin >> names[i];
/* 21 */  
/* 22 */          data[i][7] = 0; /* use last spot in array for sum, set to 0. */
/* 23 */          for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
/* 24 */              fin >> data[i][j];
/* 25 */              data[i][7] += data[i][j];
/* 26 */          }
/* 27 */      }
/* 28 */  
/* 29 */      for (int i = 0; i < numOfNames; i++)
/* 30 */      {
/* 31 */          cout << data[i][7] << endl; /* add each element to the sum here*/
/* 32 */      }
/* 33 */      return 0;
/* 34 */  }
```

OP was having a problem where no output was generated. OP, you must make sure that the your input file has the correct name...

Comment: Ok that seems like it would work but it's not outputting anything now. Here's the code

Comment: data[i][7] += data[i][j];
  }
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < numOfNames; i++)
 {
  cout << data[i][7] << endl;

 }



 system("pause");
 return 0;

}

Comment: ohhh that didn't past right, hold up I'll just edit my top question

Comment: @Ralf: I am afraid that I cannot reproduce your "no output" results. Are you sure your input file is named correctly?

Comment: Oh yeah...that was my problem. It works now! Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: also while you're here: If I wanted to put all that in a function would the prototype be

Comment: void fillAndDisplay(int data[50][8], string names[50]);

Comment: Something like that, although you have to keep track of how many names you actually have, etc.

Comment: You also wouldn't specify array size in a prototype.

Answer (score 0):

As I've answered in other similar posts:  Use a structure to model the record.

```
struct Record
{
  std::string last_name;
  std::string first_name;
  unsigned int grades[MAXIMUM_GRADES];
};
```

This allows you to have an array of mixed types:

```
Record student_info[MAXIMUM_STUDENTS];
```

To make reading from a file easier, you can overload `operator>>` inside the structure:

```
struct Record
{
  //...
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record r)
{
  std::getline(input, r.last_name, ',');
  std::getline(input, r.first_name, ' ');
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < MAXIMUM_GRADES; ++i)
  {
    input >> r.grades[i];
  }
  return input;
}
```

This simplifies your input loop:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < MAXIMUM_STUDENTS; ++i)
{
  my_data_file >> student_info[i];
}
```

Too bad you can't use `std::vector`.  The `std::vector` is ideal for reading from files *especially when you don't know the size of the file*.

Comment: this guy still don't about matrix how he could understand the struct ?

Comment: @ShahrairNazimReal: Depends on the instruction course and the order of the topics discussed.  There is no need to discuss arrays before structures.  Structures can be discussed before arrays.